# Get max of column data for entire day 7 days ago

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp, pyodbc

Using pyodbc for python and a postgreSQL database, I am looking to gather the max data of a specific day 7 days ago from the script's run date. The table has the following columns which may prove useful, Timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff), year, month, day.

I've tried the following few

```
mon = currentDate - dt.timedelta(days=7)
monPeak = cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(total) FROM {} WHERE timestamp = {};".format(tableName, mon)).fetchval()
```

Error 42883: operator does not exist: timestamp with timezone = integer

```
monPeak = cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(total) FROM {} WHERE timestamp = NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY'".format(tableName)).fetchval()
```

No error, but value is returned as 'None' (didn't think this was a viable solution anyways because I want the max of the entire day, not that specific time)

I've tried a few different ways of incorporating year, date, and time columns from db table but no good. The goal is to gather the max of data for every day of the prior week. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the timestamp to a date if you want to do date comparisons.

```
WHERE timestamp::date = (NOW() - INTERVAL '7 DAY')::date
```

Note that timestamptz to date conversions are not immutable, they depend on your current timezone setting.

Comment: That did the trick! Very much appreciated.